# Metric and partition of unité

Tags: differential-geometry

I  want somme hint about :
  I am trying to prove that each smooth manifold bas à riemannien metric using the partition of unité.

Comment: What are your attempts so far?

Comment: This is a classical result that you can easily find in any book of Riemannian geometry. 
Check also this wikipedia page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Existence_of_a_metric

Comment: I need a classical book

Comment: I  think that I need tha paracompacity hyopthesis on the manifold